# confirm choice in php page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to confirm deleting something, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When the button for 'deleteReply' I'm getting an alert message, but as far as I can tell nothing else is happening. I'm trying to simply echo the posted variable but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type="button" id="deleteSomething" value="Delete" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#deleteSomething').click(function() {
      if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
        return false;
    $.post('deleteProcessing.php', "replyID=" + replyID, function(response) {
        alert(response); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

On my delete processing page I just have

```
$echo $_POST['replyID'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteReply'])){
?>
```

Before the javascript function? Did you expect to trigger the javascript code based on the `$_POST['deleteReply']` var?

You have to keep in mind that php is processed server-side and outputs an HTML page. Your javascript code will only run in the client after all the php has run.

A much more elegant solution would be asking for a confirmation BEFORE sending the AJAX request.

And also, your ajax call doesn't seem to do what you're expecting. You're manually setting 2 parameters to send to your PHP which will have no use for it if you do the confirmation server-side.

A parameter should be something like the `Reply ID` of the reply you want to delete, and send the request to a different php file for handling.

I'd suggest you rewrite your code as Marian Zburlea is doing for you.

**EDIT**

Ok, if you want a simple confirm window, try this:

```
<input type="button" id="deleteSomething" value="Delete" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#deleteSomething').click(function() {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
            return false;

        $.post('delete.php', "replyID=" + replyID, function(response) {
            alert(response); 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple delete buttons, the best way to do this would be storing the `replyID` as the parameter to pass to your function. Echo your delete buttons in your php like this:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteSomething(\'' . $replyID . '\')" />';
```

This way, the `$replyID` will be stored in the page's HTML, which will be passed to the `deleteSomething(replyID)` function which you now have to define (preferably in the document's `head` after the JQuery lib):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteSomething(replyID)
{
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
        return false;
    $.post('deleteProcessing.php', "replyID=" + replyID, function(response) {
        alert(response); 
    });
}
</script>
```

Note that I removed the `ID` from the buttons to don't generate dupplicate IDs and they are no longer needed, as I've added a function call in the `onclick` event instead of binding an anonymous function to their IDs as you were doing previously.

Comment: Jeez, I can't believe I didn't notice that. It's been a long day.

Comment: Yes, I'd have posted this as a comment instead of an answer but it was a little bit of too long for a comment. Best of luck with that. :)

Comment: I tried Marian's suggestion, but nothing is changing. I'm still not getting a confirmation message and I don't see where it is in his code.

Comment: Try adding the HTML code (s)he added as well. It'll show the `#yesno` div when you click in the `#deleteSomething` button. It's better to comment on his/her answer. EDIT: make sure to add the JS code AFTER that part of the html or wrap it inside a `$(document).ready()` event.

Comment: I did. I swapped out my entire block of $_POST['deleteReply'] for what he has.

Comment: And nothing happens when you click in the button with `id="deleteSomething"`? Do you have more than one button with the `deleteSomething` ID?

Comment: Nope, that's the only deleteSomething ID I have. I'll update my code above...edit- Actually, there's no point to update because I copied exactly what he used. The only thing I changed was the path to my file but that shouldn't matter considering that's only triggered after the response.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not sure what the heck was going on earlier. It works now (at least the alert message).

Comment: Yes, if you have trouble with $.post or AJAX requests you should either read about it a little in the JQuery site/proper AJAX page or start a new question. Best of luck. :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help Fabricio. I've been using php for a while now, but just recently started to touch javascript so I'm still a total newb when it comes to that. Thanks again!

Comment: One more question. On the page where the message is posted to (delete.php in the example you gave), would I use $_POST['response'] to get the response or something else?  I tried to echo that and didn't get anything.

Comment: You'd use the name of the var you passed through post. Say, if inside the `$.post` you pass the parameter `replyID=123`, then you'd echo it in the php as `$_POST['replyID']`. Hope it helps :P

Comment: That's what I did (echo $_POST['replyID'] but nothing appears. I'll update my code above to show exactly what I have. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Most likely that's because the `replyID` javascript var which you're passing isn't defined, thus it echoes an empty string in your php. I used it as an example, you have to store the `replyID` somewhere while generating the page's HTML in order to be able to pass it to your other php later.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="deleteSomething" value="Delete" />
<div id="yesno" style="display:none;">
  <input type="button" id="buttonYes" value="Yes" />
  <input type="button" id="buttonNo" value="No" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Here you attach a click event to the button Yes with id buttonYes
$('#deleteSomething').click(function() {
  $('#yesno').css('display', 'block');
});
$('#buttonNo').click(function() {
  $('#yesno').css('display', 'none');
});
$('#buttonYes').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(e) {
      // Code to process before calling AJAX
    },
    url: "pathToPHPFile.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      parameter: 'Yes',
    },
    success: function (m) {
        console.log(m);
        alert(m.text);
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log("Something went wrong ...: "+e.message);
    },
  }); /* end ajax*/
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>




<?php
// This is a separate php file named pathToPHPFile.php
if(isset($_POST['parameter']) && $_POST['parameter'] == 'Yes'){
  /* here you put the code that deletes the message */
  $response['text'] = 'messageDeleted'
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm still not getting a confirmation message to appear. On second thought, where exactly is it in the code you provided?

Comment: I saw your update, but I'm still not getting a confirm/alert box to appear. Can you please comment in your code the line that triggers the confirm box because I'm not seeing it. I'm not familiar with JSON, so maybe I just don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm still not getting a confirm/alert box to appear. I removed the isset($_POST['deleteReply'])) after Fabricio pointed out javascript is client side! Anyway, why would this confirm box not appear?

Comment: Thank you for your help Marian. I really appreciate your input. I'm going to do some more research on JSON. As I stated above, I'm new to Javascript/Jquery, so I still have some reading to do. Thanks again.